# Spring Mock mvc rest-assured test fails to get status

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, rest-assured

Getting error while trying to test while running `RestAssuredMockMvc` and Spring:

```
INFO - Mapped "{[/mysql/hello],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String ee.t.mysql.controllers.testController.printHello()
INFO - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
INFO - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext@4d7cca20
INFO - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet ''
INFO - FrameworkServlet '': initialization started
INFO - FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 6 ms

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1066)
```

**UPDATE:**

fixed by changing version to 3.x:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is 99% a dependency issue. One of your jars is clashing with another version of the same jar and probably related to a servlet dependency. Can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: Here it is. How to fix it?

Comment: Is it OK to have empty name between quotation marks like this `INFO - FrameworkServlet ''` ?

Comment: I use Java 8. I had to set the api version to 4.0.1. Now it works